# How to use native query with spring repo mapped to custom object?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have table t1:

```
id | title
1  | title1
2  | title2
```

and I have the following spring repo method:

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select id, title from t1")
public List<T1> getAll();
```

The custom class is:

```
public class T1 {

@JsonProperty("id")
private Integer id;

@JsonProperty("title")
private String title;

public T1(Integer id, String title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

I'm expecting to get the following json response:

```
{[{"id":1, "title":"titl1"}, {"id":2, "title":"titl2"}]}
```

However i'm getting this one:

```
[[1,"title1"],[2,"title2"]]
```

I'm using @RestController

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntityTestResponse> test() {

    List<T1> list = testRepository.getAll();
    TestResponse response = new TestResponse(list);
    return new ResponseEntity<TestResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

TestResponse class is:

```
public class TestResponse implements Serializable {

private TreeSet<T1> list = new TreeSet<>();

public TestResponse(TreeSet<T1> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
....
```

Can you help with that?

Comment: There does not seem to be a direct link between the posted code and the JSON output.  How is the JSON output being obtained?  Is a controller involved?  What does the controller code look like?

Comment: This can't be the actual code as it won't even compile.  `repository.getAll()` returns `List`, which is being passed to `TreeResponse(TreeSet)`.  Plus, if the code was actually like what you have posted, the JSON response would be `{ "list" : [ ... ] }`.  Any way, I have copied your code to [a sample application on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/36669498) to demonstrate that the problem is neither with the query method nor with the JSON response.  You must have some custom code of your own that is creating problems with serialization.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm refactoring the code, so it changes with the time and also it's an example of my problem as i don't want to put real code publicly. Will update the post again.

Comment: Manish, i saw your code. It's working just fine because the class you are working with is actually the domain entity for that repository. What if you want to expose CompanyDto, which only contains property name? The query will look like:
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select name from company")
List<CompanyDto> getAll();
What will you get as json response in that case?

Comment: To the REST layer it doesn't matter what type of object you are dealing with - it only sees a POJO that needs to be serialized.  You can add a DTO to my sample and satisfy yourself that a DTO will serialize properly as well.  People can get to the root cause only if you provide a sample that reproduces your problem, which your current does not.

Answer (score 0):

This response is classic Java List, if you need it as JSON object, you have to use for example GSON and then you should write something like this:

```
sonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(YOUR_LIST_OF_T1));
```

[Here](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java.jsp) are examples (included that was i wrote) and  [here](https://github.com/google/gson) is GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by overrite **toString()** method in **T1** class if u need it in specific signature, and u didn't got any API doing what you want.
So if u try some thing like that

```
    List<T1> list = testRepository.getAll();
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(T1 t : list){
        strBuilder.append(t.toString() + ", ");
    }
    String result = "";
    if(strBuilder.length()!=0){
        result = "{[" + strBuilder.substring(0, strBuilder.length()-2) + "]}";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

and class should overrite toString() method

```
class T1{

@JsonProperty("id")
private Integer id;

@JsonProperty("title")
private String title;

public T1(Integer id, String title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{\"id:\"" + id + ", \"title:\"" + title + "}";
}
```

}

**Also if you want to use pure java standard library you can do it like next code** but you will need to download **javax.json-xxxx.jar**(for example >> **javax.json-1.0.4.jar**) (that include providers or the implementation) to your library project path
**But this next code will generate something like that**

> [{"id":1,"title":"Title1"},{"id":2,"title":"Title2"},{"id":3,"title":"Title3"}]

```
    List<T1> list = testRepository.getAll();

    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for(T1 t : list) {
        jsonArray.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("id", t.getId())
            .add("title", t.getTitle()));
    }
    System.out.println(jsonArray.build());
```